# How to change state of only the property that corresponds to the component it references?

Tags: reactjs

This is the current hierarchy:

**App.js:**

The state in this parent component has the following grid object:

```
  grid: [
    [{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" }],
    [{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" }],
    [{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" }],
    [{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" }],
    [{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" },{ color: "lightgray" }]
  ],
```

This grid is passed down to `GridContainer` like so:

```
render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <GridContainer grid={this.state.grid} currentColor={this.state.currentColor} handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In `GridContainer`, grid is mapped through and it generates a `RowContainer` component for every "row", which is every array of objects in the parent array.

```
{this.props.grid.map((row) => {
            return <RowContainer row={row} handleClick = {this.props.handleClick} currentColor = {this.props.currentColor}/>;
          })}
```

Likewise, in `RowContainer`, the row is mapped through and a cell is generated for every object in that array:

```
 {this.props.row.map((cell) => {
            return <Cell cell={cell} color={cell.color} handleClick = {this.props.handleClick} currentColor={this.props.currentColor}/>;
          })}
```

**Cell.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledCell = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 133px;
  height: 100px;
`;


// Give cell its own state from passed down props, and change state based on current color only when CLICKED

class Cell extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
        <StyledCell onClick={this.props.handleClick} color = {this.props.color}>
        </StyledCell>
      )
  }

}

export default Cell;
```

My question is, when a cell is clicked and the `handleClick` method in App.js is triggered, how do I instruct it to change only the `color` key value pair of that specific element in the grid?

Apologies for the lengthy post, I tried to keep it as concise as I could.

Comment: Will you show us `handleClick` please?

Comment: could you provide the code of the `cell` component ? Is it your component or a component coming from a library ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I've gone ahead and added the cell component code.

Comment: @larz handleClick is what I'm trying to write, I don't know how to begin.

Comment: @Andrew well you're in luck! Check out my answer and let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each item should ideally have a unique id.  You *could* do this with the nested indices (e.g. `grid[2][3]`) but that is not as explicit.  For example, if an item in `grid` was

```
{ color: "lightgrey", id: 123 }
```

Then in your `Row`, you can make a function to pass the id (instead of declaring it inside each cell) -

```
handleClick = id => () => this.props.handleClick(id);
```

and you can return -

```
<Cell cell={cell} color={cell.color} handleClick={this.handleClick(cell.id)} currentColor={this.props.currentColor}/>;
```

`handleClick` can take an `id` as an argument and only apply your change to that item:

```
handleClick = id => {
    const { grid } = this.state;
    const newGrid = grid.map(row => (
        row.map(cell => (
            cell.id === id ? {...cell, color: "yourNewColor" } : cell
        ))
    ));

    this.setState({ grid: newGrid });
}
```

That way, you only change the color of the specific cell you clicked, while keeping the rest of your cells in the same state they were before.

Comment: Thanks! Only thing is that this is giving me a "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","" in regards to `"yourNewColor" : cell`

Comment: Oops missed the closing `}`.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding the cell parameter to the `handleClick` function

```
{this.props.row.map((cell, index) => (
  <Cell 
     cell={cell} 
     handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
  />;
)}

class Cell extends Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.handleClick(this.props.cell)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StyledCell 
        onClick={this.handleClick} 
        color={this.props.cell.color}
      />;
  )}

}
```

Then you should update the `handleClick` function into the top Component

```
handleClick = cellToUpdate => {
    const grid = this.state.grid.map(
      row => row.map(cell => cell === cellToUpdate ? {color: "red"} : cell
    );

    this.setState({ grid });
}
```

Note that using this method will create an extra function for each cell

If you absolutly want to declare only one function, you should consider passing `data-attributes` to `StyledCell` (`data-rowIndex` and `data-columnIndex`) and retrieve them  into the `handleClick` function with `event.currentTarget.dataset.rowIndex` and `event.currentTarget.dataset.columnIndex`